# Surjective homomorphism from a Noetherian ring to another ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, noetherian

Let $f:A\to B$ be a surjective ring homomorphism and assume $A$ is Noetherian.

We want to show that $B$ is also Noetherian.

This question was similarly asked, but I wanted to get some clarification on some differences:

$\textbf{Proof Sketch}$

Take any ideal in $B$, say $J$, and its preimage, say $J'\in A$ and show it's an ideal (I know this is true from a previous result I proved)

Since the $J'$ lives in $A$, it is finitely generated, say $\langle a_1,...,a_l\rangle=J'$

We then show $\langle f(a_1),...,f(a_l)\rangle=J$ Thus every ideal of $B$ is finitely generated

Questions:

1) Does this work?

2) Technically by definition, we define Noetherian rings to be commutative, is that necessary for $B$ here? (Or should I assume $B$ is commutative?)

3) Did we ever need the homomorphism to be surjective?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, this works, although you're sweeping something under the rug (namely, in your statement "We then show $\langle f(a_1),\dots, f(a_\ell)\rangle = J$").
2. If $A$ is commutative and admits a surjection to $B$, $B$ must also be commutative: any $b,b'\in B$ are images of some $a,a'\in A$, and so
   $$
   b b' = f(a) f(a') = f(a a') = f(a' a) = f(a') f(a) = b' b.
   $$
3. Surjectivity is definitely needed. $\Bbb Z$ is noetherian, and admits a ring map to any other ring $R$ with unity, even if $R$ is nonnoetherian. This is what you swept under the rug, as I mentioned earlier. If $f : A\to B$ is not surjective, you might not have $f(J') = J$: in general, given a map of sets $g : X\to Y$ and a subset $S\subseteq Y$, you have $f(f^{-1}(S))\subseteq S$, but not necessarily equality. For an example, consider the map
   \begin{align*}
   g : \{\ast\}&\to\Bbb Z\\
   \ast&\mapsto 0.
   \end{align*}
   Then $g^{-1}(\Bbb Z) = \{\ast\}$, but $g(\{\ast\}) = \{0\}\subsetneq\Bbb Z$. Although this is only an argument for maps of sets, the same phenomenon can happen with ring maps.

Comment: Yes that made a lot of sense thank you! Didn't realize that when I look at other elements in $J$ (not just zero), it's possible they didn't get mapped to (if not surjective). Question: in the final statement, is $\left\{0\right\}=S$ or is $\mathbb{Z}=S$?

Comment: @northcity4 In the example, $\Bbb Z = Y = S\supsetneq g(g^{-1}(S)) = g(\{\ast\}) = \{0\}$.